# integrality of terms of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

The sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is defined by 
$a_i=i$ for $i=1,2,3$
and satisfies $$a_{i}=\dfrac{a_{i-1}a_{i-2}+7}{a_{i-3}}, i \ge 4.$$
The question is to prove that all terms of the sequence are integers.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Are you familiar with induction? To be clear, I haven't tried it, but this problem seems to doable via induction.

Comment: This is to broad: try with induction. How?

Comment: Hint : The exponential growing of the terms $a_i$ suggests a simpler underlying recurrence relation. This is indeed the case and you will find two sequences for even and odd coefficients described by the same second order recurrence relation $a_{n}=p a_{n-2} + q a_{n-4}$ for some constants $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @Ronald Blaak your sequence can actually be simplified into a simpler sequence $a_i=8a_{i-2}-a_{i-4}$. To prove this you can use induction: the base case is trivial, suppose now that you know it is true for all $j\le{}i$ then multiplying both sides by $a_{i-1}$ and dividing with $a_{i-2}$ we get $a_{i+1}=\frac{7+a_ia_{i-1}}{a_{i-2}}=\frac{8a_{i-2}a_{i-1}}{a_{i-2}}-\frac{a_{i-4}a_{i-1}+7}{a_{i-2}}$, but $a_{i-4}a_{i-1}=a_{i-2}a_{i-3}+7$ and thus $a_{i+1}=\frac{a_{i-4}a_{i-1}+7}{a_{i-2}}=8a_{i-1}-a_{i-3}$ which completes the proof.

Comment: The factor 16 should be 8

Comment: If I am not mistaken aren't the first terms $a_4=8, a_5=15, a_6=127, a_7=239$ ? This gives $a_5=16-1, a_6= 16\times{}8-1, a_7=16\times{}15-1$ etc.

Comment: No, since $a_i=i$ (not 1) for i=1,2,3, we have $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, and hence $a_4=13$, $a_5=23$, ... The technique for solving the problem of course is not affected by the initial conditions of the sequence. Also note there is a small typo in the denominator of your first fraction ($a_2$ should be $a_{i-2}$).

Comment: Ah thank you I misread $a_i=1$ for $i=1,2,3$...